# Replace one delimiter with another in Spark data frame in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my Spark data frame output of **dfMainOutput**.

```
4295858898,177,SelfSourcedPublic,INC,Cost of sales,Umsatzkosten,,ECOR,false,,,,,false,False,,,,505096,505074,505074,505096,505096,,505074,False,,3014830,,I|!|
```

Now i want to replace `,` with `|^|` and dropping one column **DataPartition**

This is what I am doing:

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

val headerColumn = df.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq

val header = headerColumn.dropRight(1).mkString("", "|^|", "|!|")

val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)


dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition","StatementTypeCode")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialLineItem/output")
```

With this code the output below is generated:

```
4295858898|^|177|^|INC|^|Cost of sales|^|Umsatzkosten|^|ECOR|^|false|^|false|^|False|^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^|505074|^|False|^|3014830|^|I|!|
```

Where empty elements are missing. I would like it to be:

```
4295858898|^|177|^|INC|^|Cost of sales|^|Umsatzkosten|^||^|ECOR|^|False|^||^||^||^||^|False|^|False|^||^||^||^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^||^|505074|^|False|^||^|3014830|^||^|I|!|
```

Also in the data frame output i am getting `false` where as we want `False`
Please help me what II am missing ..

Here is my schema

```
root
 |-- LineItem_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- LineItem_lineItemId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LineItemName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LocalLanguageLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptLocal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptGlobal: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsDimensional: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- InstrumentId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LineItemSequence: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PhysicalMeasureId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondary: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsRangeAllowed: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- IsSegmentedByOrigin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentGroupDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentChildDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LocalLanguageLabel_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LineItemName_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentChildDescription_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentGroupDescription_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentMultipleFundbDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SegmentMultipleFundbDescription_languageId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsCredit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptLocalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptGlobalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
```

In the data `DataPartition=SelfSourcePublic and StatementTypeCode=INC`

Output from dfMaainOutput

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------+
|LineItem_organizationId|LineItem_lineItemId|DataPartition    |StatementTypeCode|LineItemName                                                                              |LocalLanguageLabel                                                                                    |FinancialConceptLocal|FinancialConceptGlobal|IsDimensional|InstrumentId|LineItemSequence|PhysicalMeasureId|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondary|IsRangeAllowed|IsSegmentedByOrigin|SegmentGroupDescription|SegmentChildDescription|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel|LocalLanguageLabel_languageId|LineItemName_languageId|SegmentChildDescription_languageId|SegmentChildLocalLanguageLabel_languageId|SegmentGroupDescription_languageId|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription|SegmentMultipleFundbDescription_languageId|IsCredit|FinancialConceptLocalId|FinancialConceptGlobalId|FinancialConceptCodeGlobalSecondaryId|FFAction|
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------+
|4295858898             |707                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Revenue from long-term construction contracts                                             |Erlöse aus langfristigen Fertigungsaufträgen                                                          |null                 |ROBR                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3015278                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295858898             |3289               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Balancing Item - Net Income available to Controlling Interest                             |null                                                                                                  |null                 |IIII                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3014960                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295858922             |808                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Income Taxes - Total                                                                      |Ertragsteuern                                                                                         |null                 |XTAX                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3019589                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295858922             |1507               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Balancing Item - Operating Expenses                                                       |null                                                                                                  |null                 |IIII                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3014960                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295858951             |1574               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Admin/General Expenses                                                                    |null                                                                                                  |null                 |ESGA                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3018991                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859007             |1645               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Exploration Expenses - Balancing value                                                    |null                                                                                                  |null                 |EEXP                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3018916                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859038             |954                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Sale Investments                                                                          |null                                                                                                  |null                 |EGFA                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3018929                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859038             |1967               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Restructuring Charges/Provisions                                                          |Ergebnis aus Umstrukturierungen                                                                       |null                 |ERES                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3018980                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859038             |1996               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Diluted Weighted Average Shares on Instrument Level multiplied to its Participation Factor|null                                                                                                  |null                 |DWASEPFI              |false        |8590926849  |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |1002023919              |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859045             |864                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Results of valuation gains/losses and disposals of non-current securities                 |Ergebnis aus Kursänderungen und Abgängen von Wertpapieren des langfristigen Finanzvermögens („@FVTPL“)|null                 |EGIT                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3018932                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859045             |1092               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Excep. Depreciation                                                                       |null                                                                                                  |null                 |EGLO                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3018938                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859071             |1840               |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Other Operating Expense                                                                   |null                                                                                                  |null                 |EOOE                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3018974                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859078             |914                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Balancing Item - Non Operating Income/(Expense), net                                      |null                                                                                                  |null                 |IIII                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505096                       |505074                 |505074                            |505096                                   |505096                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3014960                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859106             |514                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Personnel Expenses                                                                        |null                                                                                                  |null                 |ELAS                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |3018944                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859106             |903                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Balancing Item - Non Operating Income/(Expense), net                                      |null                                                                                                  |null                 |IIII                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3014960                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859216             |499                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |BC - Depreciation of Fixed Assets                                                         |null                                                                                                  |null                 |BCDEP                 |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505084                       |505074                 |505074                            |505084                                   |505084                            |null                           |505074                                    |False   |null                   |1002023928              |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859236             |172                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Total Revenue                                                                             |Ventes                                                                                                |null                 |XTLR                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3016345                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859241             |492                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Diluted Net Income excluding Extra Items applicable to Common - (Instrument Level)        |null                                                                                                  |null                 |XNCNDI                |false        |8589989623  |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |1001214357              |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859279             |124                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Income Available to Com Excl ExtraOrd                                                     |Toerekenbaar aan de aandeelhouders van de moederonderneming                                           |null                 |XNCN                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |False              |null                   |null                   |null                          |505084                       |505074                 |505074                            |505084                                   |505084                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3016316                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
|4295859298             |488                |SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |Other operating income/expenses                                                           |Other operating expenses                                                                              |null                 |EOIE                  |false        |null        |null            |null             |null                               |false         |null               |null                   |null                   |null                          |505074                       |505074                 |505074                            |505074                                   |505074                            |null                           |505074                                    |True    |null                   |3018969                 |null                                 |I|!|    |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------+
```

Output After Code

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))
```

Here is output

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|DataPartition    |StatementTypeCode|concatenated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295858898|^|707|^|INC|^|Revenue from long-term construction contracts|^|Erlöse aus langfristigen Fertigungsaufträgen|^|ROBR|^|false|^|false|^|False|^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^|505074|^|True|^|3015278|^|I|!|                                                                                      |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295858898|^|3289|^|INC|^|Balancing Item - Net Income available to Controlling Interest|^|IIII|^|false|^|false|^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^|505074|^|True|^|3014960|^|I|!|                                                                                                                            |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295858922|^|808|^|INC|^|Income Taxes - Total|^|Ertragsteuern|^|XTAX|^|false|^|false|^|False|^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^|505074|^|False|^|3019589|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                             |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295858922|^|1507|^|INC|^|Balancing Item - Operating Expenses|^|IIII|^|false|^|false|^|505096|^|505074|^|505074|^|505096|^|505096|^|505074|^|True|^|3014960|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                                      |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295859236|^|172|^|INC|^|Total Revenue |^|Ventes|^|XTLR|^|false|^|false|^|False|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|True|^|3016345|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                                           |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295859241|^|492|^|INC|^|Diluted Net Income excluding Extra Items applicable to Common - (Instrument Level) |^|XNCNDI|^|false|^|8589989623|^|false|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|True|^|1001214357|^|I|!|                                                                                     |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295859279|^|124|^|INC|^|Income Available to Com Excl ExtraOrd|^|Toerekenbaar aan de aandeelhouders van de moederonderneming|^|XNCN|^|false|^|false|^|False|^|505084|^|505074|^|505074|^|505084|^|505084|^|505074|^|True|^|3016316|^|I|!|                                                                               |
|SelfSourcedPublic|INC              |4295859298|^|488|^|INC|^|Other operating income/expenses|^|Other operating expenses|^|EOIE|^|false|^|false|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|505074|^|True|^|3018969|^|I|!|                                                                                                                                |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So just be make clear for example `4295858898             |3289` null value in the column `LocalLanguageLabel` is gone

I dont know how it is missed ...

Comment: This is exactly what it produces for me, when I execute your code. `val test = (432343, 177, "Cost of sales", "Umsatzkosten", "" ,"Ecor", false, "", "", "", false)` and `val df = List(test).toDF()` and `df.select(concat_ws("|^|", df.schema.fieldNames.map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated")).collect().head` result in `[432343|^|177|^|Cost of sales|^|Umsatzkosten|^||^|Ecor|^|false|^||^||^||^|false]`. Could you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: @Anupam I use spark version 2.2.0 with scala 2.11.8 and Java 1.8.0_152. Could you try with the code from my comment and see if you can reproduce your problem with it? Then it looks like a problem with your version. You would need to replace "DataPartition" with "_3" and "StatementTypeCode" with "_4" in my example.

Comment: I am also using same version but not sure what am i missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main culprit is that you have `null` values in your `dataframe` and `concat_ws` is filtering out all the null values. So **the solution is to replace all `null` values to `""`** which should solve your issue. It won't be a problem as you have all the `null` datatypes in schema as `string`.

So, replacing the following

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))
```

with

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition", $"StatementTypeCode",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))
```

should solve your issue